# item.match is not a function in React Native

Tags: react-native

im having this error every time i type even one letter in my search bar and i dont know how to fix. sorry noob dev

```
    const [dataList] = useState(data)
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(dataList);
    const onSearch = (text) => {
      if (text) {
      const temp = text.toLowerCase();
      const tempList = dataList.filter(item => {
         if (item.match(temp))
            return item
      })
      setFiltered(tempList);
      setSearching(true);
      }
         else {
            setFiltered(dataList);
            setSearching(false);
         }
    };
```

[here is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2dSe.png)

Comment: one thing, temp here is a string, where if you use item.match(/*regex exp*/) it should be a regex expression but thats secondary can you please console.log(item) and share me

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe item is not a String, it needs to be.

and another syntax advice.

change to return item.match(temp)